# How to Merge the List in Linq Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this Linq queries,when i run those queries i got the result,which i shown in img below

```
var SalesinvDets = (from si in CustomerTransactions
                            where si.TransTypeID == 10
                            group new {si} by new{
         month=si.Period==1?"Jan-2015":si.Period==2?"Feb-2015":si.Period==3?"Mar-2015":si.Period==4?"Apr-2015":si.Period==5?"May-2015":
                                si.Period==6?"Jun-2015":si.Period==7?"Jul-2015":si.Period==8?"Aug-2015":si.Period==9?"Sep-2015":si.Period==10?"Oct-2015":
                                si.Period==11?"Nov-2015":si.Period==12?"Dec-2015":"",   
        month2=si.Period==13?"Jan-2016":si.Period==14?"Feb-2016":si.Period==15?"Mar-2016":si.Period==16?"Apr-2016":si.Period==17?"May-2016":
                                si.Period==18?"Jun-2016":si.Period==19?"Jul-2016":si.Period==20?"Aug-2016":si.Period==21?"Sep-2016":
                                si.Period==22?"Oct-2016":si.Period==23?"Nov-2016":si.Period==24?"Dec-2016":"",
                            period=si.Period
                            } into g    
                            select new
                            {    
                                month=g.Key.month,
                                month2=g.Key.month2,
                                Amount = g.Sum(x=>x.si.OVAmount)//.Sum(x=>x.si.OVAmount-(x.si.OVDiscount+x.si.OVFreight))//(si.OVAmount - (si.OVDiscount + si.OVFreight))
                            }).Dump();
```

I got this result during run the query,but i dont need like that

[image: Linq Error]

I need the result like that,pls help to achieve my task

[image: result img]

Comment: The groupby isn't working the way you want.  I wouldadd  an inheritance to the class IComparable with the method CompareTo(). The Linq Groupby will use the CompareTo method for the groupings. You have a complicated GroupBy and it is much easier to code as a function.  You could also create a helper function to do the Grouping which is the equivalent of the CompareTo() method which would return an integer (-1 ,0,1).

Answer (score 2):

Issue exist due to faulty `GroupBy` statement, it is based on the value of `si.Period`, which will be any one of the values specified in `month` and `month2`, therefore in each grouping either `month` or `month2` will be `empty string ""`, both will never be filled, thus the result that you have shown, solution for the same would be separate grouping based on `month` and `month2`, as follows:

```
var SalesinvDetsMonthList = (from si in CustomerTransactions
                            where si.TransTypeID == 10
                            group new {si} by new{
         month=si.Period==1?"Jan-2015":si.Period==2?"Feb-2015":si.Period==3?"Mar-2015":si.Period==4?"Apr-2015":si.Period==5?"May-2015":
                                si.Period==6?"Jun-2015":si.Period==7?"Jul-2015":si.Period==8?"Aug-2015":si.Period==9?"Sep-2015":si.Period==10?"Oct-2015":
                                si.Period==11?"Nov-2015":si.Period==12?"Dec-2015":"",   

                            period=si.Period
                            } into g    
                            select new
                            {    
                                Month=g.Key.month
                                Amount = g.Sum(x=>x.si.OVAmount)//.Sum(x=>x.si.OVAmount-(x.si.OVDiscount+x.si.OVFreight))
                            }).Where( x => x.month != "").ToList(); // Removing empty month values / default values


var SalesinvDetsMonth2List = (from si in CustomerTransactions
                            where si.TransTypeID == 10
                            group new {si} by new{
         month2=si.Period==13?"Jan-2016":si.Period==14?"Feb-2016":si.Period==15?"Mar-2016":si.Period==16?"Apr-2016":si.Period==17?"May-2016":
                                si.Period==18?"Jun-2016":si.Period==19?"Jul-2016":si.Period==20?"Aug-2016":si.Period==21?"Sep-2016":
                                si.Period==22?"Oct-2016":si.Period==23?"Nov-2016":si.Period==24?"Dec-2016":"",
                            period=si.Period
                            } into g    
                            select new
                            {    
                                month=g.Key.month,
                                Month2=g.Key.month2,
                                Amount2 = g.Sum(x=>x.si.OVAmount)//.Sum(x=>x.si.OVAmount-(x.si.OVDiscount+x.si.OVFreight))//(si.OVAmount - (si.OVDiscount + si.OVFreight))
                            }).Where( x => x.month != "").ToList(); // Removing empty month values / default values
```

Now we need to merge the two lists created above:

```
SalesinvDetsMonthList, SalesinvDetsMonth2List
```

For which I assume, they have same number of records,, now you need a combined entity like:

```
public class SalesinvDetsMonthCombined
{
  public string Month {get; set;}
  public string Month2 {get; set;}
  public int Amount {get; set;}
  public int Amount2 {get; set;}
}

int totalCount = SalesinvDetsMonthList.Count;

List<SalesinvDetsMonthCombined> result = new List<SalesinvDetsMonthCombined>();

for (int index=0, index < totalCount; index ++)
{
  result.Add(new SalesinvDetsMonthCombined
                ( Month = SalesinvDetsMonthList[index].Month,
                  Month2 = SalesinvDetsMonth2List[index].Month2,
                  Amount = SalesinvDetsMonthList[index].Amount,
                  Amount2 = SalesinvDetsMonth2List[index].Amount2
                ));
}
```

However please note, above code is based on assumption that you have provided, that there are matching records, in case there's discrepancy in the number of records, then you need to add a default, else it will fail

Comment: int totalCount = SalesinvDetsMonth.Count;

List<SalesinvDetsMonthCombined> result = new List<SalesinvDetsMonthCombined>();

for (int index=0, index < totalCount; index ++)
{
  result.Add(new SalesinvDetsMonthCombined
                ( Month = SalesinvDetsMonthList[index].Month,
                  Month2 = SalesinvDetsMonth2List[index].Month2,
                  Amount = SalesinvDetsMonthList[index].Amount,
                  Amount2 = SalesinvDetsMonth2List[index].Amount2
                ));
}   hi mrinal iam getting error on this code , i didnt understood these steps pls explain me

Comment: What's the error, index out of range ? as I have suggested success of the solution depends on the fact that both list have same number of records, else you need a default, also a minor edit to the code, check that ?